# Companion objects that hold both a default instance AND values that get manipulated before being passed as default arguments -> NPE

Tags: scala

I feel like this should go in ScalaPuzzlers if it isn't there already, but it looks like companion objects that hold both a default instance AND values that get manipulated before being passed as default arguments to their companion result in NPE if the values being held in it are not lazy.

I created a gist demonstrating that (in a contrived way) in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/lloydmeta/196cac75884b682e4acd), but the code is as follows:

```
object Dummy {
  val emptyDummy = Dummy()
  val names: Seq[String] = Seq("Bob", "John", "Mary")
}

case class Dummy(names: Seq[String] = Dummy.names.map(_ + "_screwed"))

/*
scala> Dummy()
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at Dummy$.apply$default$1(<console>:13)
  ... 35 elided

scala> Dummy()
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class Dummy$
  ... 33 elided
*/

/* This works, though the empty object has a null in it */

object Dummy {
  val emptyDummy = Dummy()
  val names: Seq[String] = Seq("Bob", "John", "Mary")
}

case class Dummy(names: Seq[String] = Dummy.names)

/*
scala> Dummy()
res0: Dummy = Dummy(List(Bob, John, Mary))

scala> Dummy.emptyDummy
res1: Dummy = Dummy(null)
*/

/* This also works (making the val lazy) */

object Dummy {
  val emptyDummy = Dummy()
  lazy val names: Seq[String] = Seq("Bob", "John", "Mary")
}

case class Dummy(names: Seq[String] = Dummy.names.map(_ + "_screwed"))

/*
scala> Dummy()
res0: Dummy = Dummy(List(Bob_screwed, John_screwed, Mary_screwed))

scala> Dummy.emptyDummy
res1: Dummy = Dummy(List(Bob_screwed, John_screwed, Mary_screwed))
*/
```

Does anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example looks like ti usage of forwarding reference: constructor of `Dummy` for `emptyDummy` instance called before `names` inited:

```
object Dummy {
  val emptyDummy = Dummy()
  val names: Seq[String] = Seq("Bob", "John", "Mary")
}

case class Dummy(names: Seq[String] = Dummy.names.map(_ + "_screwed"))
```

Try swap lines in object code:

```
object Dummy {
  val names: Seq[String] = Seq("Bob", "John", "Mary")
  val emptyDummy = Dummy()
}
```

Comment: I think this makes sense; the forward reference is what causes problems when not using lazy.

The first case breaks because the `val emptyDummy` tries to do `Dummy()`, but the default argument of `Dummy` relies on something that is null when `emptyDummy` is being defined, since it comes later.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe of interest:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5366

I have to say more because the URL doesn't count toward the min length.

It doesn't warn about:

```
scala> object X {
     | val d = f
     | val z = List(1,2,3)
     | def f = z
     | }
defined object X

scala> X.d
res5: List[Int] = null
```